# `tr` replaces more than I expected

Tags: macos, find-and-replace, string-manipulation

I have a load of files from my teaching job that I want to put in OneDrive on a regular backup. My colleagues are bad at naming files, so they need a cleanup for OneDrive to take them.

The bit that I can't get is how to select a space before a period.

I'm trying this

```
bash-3.2$ echo "foo bar .pdf" | tr -s " \." '\.'
```

and getting this

`foo.bar.pdf` instead of `foo bar.pdf`. What is wrong with my command?

Comment: Just discovered detox in home-brew, which is brilliant to cleanup bad filenames that stop onedrive running. Runs brilliantly.  http://detox.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` replaces *single* characters with single characters and you told it to replace each space and each dot with dot (except `-s` squeezes space+dot into a single entity to replace). In other words one space-or-dot is enough to trigger your `tr`.

To replace strings use `sed`:

```
echo "foo bar .pdf" | sed 's/ \././g'
```

Note: I used `g` because `tr` you used acts globally, so I assumed this is what you want in general (it doesn't matter for this particular string `foo bar .pdf`).